# Multilevel Nested Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I realize this code has many issues stopping what my goal is here.  So here are my goals.  I would like to have a dynamic form that can add nested elements, preferably without a limit to the levels, but at least about 9 levels.  I want the user to see one button when they start, and be able to add items, and then various items beneath each of those items, but then add another group of that same type.  I'd like the button appended to be able to append the next level of depth.  I'd like to add form fields as needed for different items that are added.  So, simply:

1. Multi-level Nested Buttons
2. Each button or section (button and field) are removable

Please let me know if you have other questions.  I cannot seem to format this to get the sections nested and changeable.  Thanks for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("ol").append(" <b>New Item</b>.");
    });

    $("#btn2").on("click", function(){
        $("ol").append("<li>New Item Title</li><input type='text'><br /><button id='btn1'>Add Nested Item</button><br /><br />");
    });


});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">


var counter = 0;

$("button").click(function() {
    $("h2").append("<p class='test'>click me " + (++counter) + "</p>")
});

// With on():

$("h2").on("click", "p.test", function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});


</script>


<button id="btn2">Add Item</button>



<form>
<ol>

</ol>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you including jQuery 3.1.1 and 1.8.3 ?

Comment: I'm using jquery to get the append function.  Please help.